# Failed to configure a DataSource in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Good day. I'm getting this error when trying to run the server.Tried many things which led me to nowhere in the end..

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jokes
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password123
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**folder structure**

[image]

**application**

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.jokes.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.jokes.repositories")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {UserController.class})
//        exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}
public class JokesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JokesApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public UserService userService() {
        return new UserService();
    }
```

**jokes pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>jokes-data</module>
        <module>jokes-web</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jokes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jokes</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>/home/name/Desktop/Java Projects/jokes/jokes-web/src/main/java/com/example/jokes/JokesApplication.java</mainClass>
<!--                    <mainClass>com/example/jokes/JokesApplication.java</mainClass>-->
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goals>install</goals>
                    <checkModificationExcludes>pom.xml</checkModificationExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:h1dd33n/jokes.git</developerConnection>
      <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>

</project>
```

**joke-data pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>jokes</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>jokes-data</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>/home/name/Desktop/Java Projects/jokes/jokes-web/src/main/java/com/example/jokes/JokesApplication.java</mainClass>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**joke-web pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>jokes</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>jokes-web</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>jokes-data</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.4</version>
                <configuration>
                        <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`application.properties` are inside `jokes/src/main/resources`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Would you like the data source setup properly, or are you trying to prevent Spring trying to setup the data source automatically? There are 2 right answers the the question as it's currently worded, fix the database configuration or disable the data source.

Comment: I'm trying to get the data source setup properly.

Comment: @AlexScott do you have any ideas why the data source isn't configuring properly?

Comment: Remove `spring-boot-maven-plpugin` from the `jokes-data` project. Rebuild. Assuming that your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in `com.example.jokes` remove allt he annotations and just leave a plain `@SpringBootApplication`, all the others aren't needed. Finally your `application.properties` is simply in the wrong directory. The other projects don't look in the parent for the properties, you either need to put them in datas or web.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please make sure that your properties file are actually available to your modules?

From my point of view, your properties file sits in the parent directory, without any access for the two modules. Please check the target folder of your modules and see if it contains the properties file. If it does not you will have to setup the maven copy ressources plugin as follows:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html